# Gmail & font-family inline style

Tags: email, fonts, gmail

I'm having an email template with tables nested each other, images & text.  I gave to the td tag with the text an inline style with font-family: Arial; but it seams that gmail on android (app and web) using some other font as default, my inline style has no effect on it.

I have tried using "font" instead of "font-family" and font tag with face="Arial", nothing helps.

Why is that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`Arial` is not a font installed on Android, and it aliased to `Roboto` instead. As a general rule, it is also a good practice to always a font family as the last keyword in your font stack. Like so:

```css
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
```

Comment: Thank you, so what if I want to use a font for most devices and email clients, which one to choose? I need it to look the same, the lines to break the same.

Comment: You can’t. You need to define fonts and fallbacks that are similar enough to break the same way. (Usually, Arial, Helvetica and Roboto are **very** similar.) You can also try using `&nbsp;` between words that you want to break together.